# Sharing storage between instances

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using the Engine Yard AppCloud service.

If I want my instances to share storage (e.g. for file uploads/downloads), is my only real option to build S3 integration into my application? At the moment the app expects to use the filsystem but it doesn't look like multiple instances can mount the same EBS volume.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the simple option is to have an NFS server, have the EBS mounted on it and share that to the instances.

But there are other distributed filesystem that you can use also like glusterfs,moosefs and the like.

Answer (score 1):

There are some shared filesystems that may work on EC2 or AppCloud without a problem however the support of them likely would be 0.

Otherwise I would suggest to look into using [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon)

- MogileFS
- GlusterFS