# File system like alternative to s3 on EC2 for horizontally scalable file storage?

Tags: filesystems, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Terabytes worth of files will still be served over s3 and CDN, but many local binary operations need to take place, and existing application logic prefers local copies of files.

The goal is to have s3 like abilities, with filesystem like interface and performance.

Examples might be:

- glusterFS
- s3Fuse
- MooseFS

Document stores aren't quite the same thing:

- HDFS
- GridFS (MongoDB)
- CouchDB

Reasons to not use only s3:

- legacy code which uses a local filesystem
- legacy operational code which expects local filesystem
- network latency on some of these operations
- product lock in

Comment: Since you are already in the AWS cloud, why not just use S3 for the store (since you are still going to be using it) and just pull the files you need onto the instance as you need to process them?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329980/sharing-storage-between-instances

Comment: @cdeszaq a few reasons

 - legacy application code that depends on "instant" local copies
 - legacy automation code
 - network latency when offline processing isn't the goal
 - no lockin to S3

Comment: Its hard to answer without knowing more, like the number of EC2 instances, whether the storage must be shared between them etc. If it is just a single EC2 instance then are you essentially looking for something like an expandable EBS store that is backed up automatically to S3 for persistence?

Comment: EBS limitations are really the issue. EBS based on ZFS might also work? http://blogs.oracle.com/ec2/entry/ebs_is_supported_on_opensolaris

Comment: There is a ZFS for ubuntu now https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable/ - unless I'm mistaken that ZFS can not have multiple clients and function as a NAS.